# Why can't I call a function from another function in javascript?

Tags: javascript, function, methods

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<head>
<title>
Math game</title>
</head>

<body onload = "guess()">

<script>

function guess(){
var userGuess = prompt("Guess a positive number less than 50");
var userRandomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 49) + 1;
check(userGuess,userRandomNumber);
}

</script>

<script>

function check(guess,randomNumber){

if(parseInt(guess)<0 ){
    alert('Please enter a number in the given range');
    guess();
}else if(parseInt(guess)>=50){
    alert('Please enter a number in the given range');
    guess();
}
else if (parseInt(guess) === randomNumber ) {
    alert('You guessed the number!');
} else if(parseInt(guess) > randomNumber ) {
    alert('Sorry. The number was ' + randomNumber);
}else{
    alert('Sorry. The number was ' + randomNumber );
}
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

So this is a number guessing game and I want to prompt the user to enter a number again if the user enters a number out of the range.So I want to call guess() function from check() function.But this code will not give the result.Do I need to create an object of type guess like you do in Java?If that is the case then how do I properly create the object? Any help is appreciated =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short Answer**

Rename argument `guess` in your `check` function to anything else.

**Detailed Answer**

Argument in your `check` function *`guess`* is creating a variable with the name *`guess`* in the local scope of the function.

When you change it's name to something else, say *`guessnumber`*. It will not find *`guess`* in the local scope of a function and will try to access the variable with the same name in the parent scope (which is global scope in your case) and it will find the function with name *`guess`* and your code will work perfectly fine.

To understand this, alternatively you can also change call to *`guess`* function in your *`check`* function from *`guess()`* to *`window.guess()`* which will also make your code functionally correct (In this case it will directly look for function with name *`guess`* in global scope however the approach is not recommended.

Read more [here](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/tree/master/scope%20%26%20closures)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help and the explanation

Answer (score 1):

You are using the same name for the function and the parameter: `guess`.

Change the parameter name to something else:

```html
<head>
<title>
Math game</title>
</head>

<body onload = "guess()">

<script>

function guess(){
var userGuess = prompt("Guess a positive number less than 50");
var userRandomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 49) + 1;
check(userGuess,userRandomNumber);
}

function check(guessNumber,randomNumber){

if(parseInt(guessNumber)<0 ){
    alert('Please enter a number in the given range');
    guess();
}else if(parseInt(guessNumber)>=50){
    alert('Please enter a number in the given range');
    guess();
}
else if (parseInt(guessNumber) === randomNumber ) {
    alert('You guessed the number!');
} else if(parseInt(guessNumber) > randomNumber ) {
    alert('Sorry. The number was ' + randomNumber);
}else{
    alert('Sorry. The number was ' + randomNumber );
}
}
</script>

</body>
```